# if statement for global variable in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile in which I am using some global variables like

```
REL=something..

DIR=something...
```

This makefile is used to build two products say P1 and P2, based on product for which it is build value of global variables is getting used which was not an issue because value of all the global variables for both the product was same, but now the value of variable REL is different for product 1 and Product 2, I was trying this but its not working:

```
!IF "$(PRODUCT)"=="P1"

REL=value1

!ELSEIF "$(PRODUCT)"=="P2"

REL=value2

!ENDIF
```

Comment: What kind of makefile syntax is `!ELSEIF`? Could you re-word your main paragraph so it isn't one huge sentence that doesn't make sense?

Comment: That is not make, that is automake syntax.  Two very different macro constructs.

Answer (score 1):

If I undertand your question correctly (a big if), then you can do it with [target-specific variable values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
P1: REL=product1
P1: some_preq
    do_something...

P2: REL=product2
P2: some_other_preq
    do_something_else...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using both make or automake, then you can do as @Beta suggested.  In make, definition checks are done as follows:

```
ifeq (P1,$(PRODUCT))
REL:=value1
endif

ifeq (P2,$(PRODUCT))
REL:=value2
endif
```

The better way to do what you are trying to do is as @Beta suggested.  Create PHONY targets if you have to.